# Как правильно задействовать интерфейс в двух классах?

Tags: java, android, наследование

Всем привет! Я пишу плеер под Android и у меня сейчас такая картина:

1. Класс активности. На ней расположен список музыкальных треков, а также нижняя панель. На панели есть кнопки "Back", " Play/Pause" и "Next", а также название трека и его автора.
2. Класс адаптера списка. В списке каждый элемент имеет название и автора трека, а также либо первую букву названия трека в кружке (если этот трек не играет), либо `ProgressBar` (если идет подготовка к проигрыванию), либо `MiniEqualizer` (если музыка играет), либо иконка `Play` (если музыка стоит на паузе). Нажатие по итему (элементу списка) начинает проигрывание трека, повторное нажатие ставит на паузу.
3. Класс плеера. В нем сидит `MediaPlayer`, отвечающий за проигрывание музыки, в этом классе есть методы для управления проигрыванием, там же хранится информация о проигрываемом треке, и еще есть методы геттеры возвращающие эту информацию.
4. Интерфейс `PlayBack`. Вот тут собственно и вопрос. Я создал интерфейс (не будем усложнять, пусть будут только `play` и `pause` методы). По нажатию на паузу из нижней панели в итеме списка эквалайзер должен поменяться на значок `Play`. Аналогично и с остановкой музыки из списка и сменой картинки в нижней панели. Тоесть, простым, языком, нижняя панель (активность) и список (адаптер) должны быть взаимно связаны, вот я и решил прибегнуть к интерфейсу. Изначально экземпляр класса `Player` создается в активности, затем передается в адаптер. Я вызываю его методы, там они дергают методы интерфейса, и таким образом реализовал связь двух классов.

**Проблема-то какая?**

Я передаю 2 `Playback`-а в класс плеера: один для активности, второй для адаптера, и вызываю их методы в двух местах. Нельзя ли как-нибудь вызвать в одном?

Comment: Паттерн "наблюдатель" в помощь. Подпишитесь своей активностью на изменения в `MediaPlayer`. А он в свою очередь, когда кто-то поменяет состояние (не важно кто), уведомит всех подписчиков об этом изменении. Как только активити получит это уведомление, обновит список и обновит панельку.

Comment: @Vladimir Parfenov, значит все-таки есть что-то! Наблюдатель значит. Где про него почитать? :)

Comment: Да хоть в гугле. Но мне понравилось объяснение в книге Head First "Паттерны проектирования".

Comment: @Vladimir Parfenov, что ж вы сразу не сказали - обсервер? :)

Comment: Ну уж перевести Вы в состоянии )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

у медиаплеера есть набор интерфейсов лисенеров на все события. К примеру  `myMediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(OnCompletionListener (activity or adapter))`
Подробнее почитайте в  [документации](https://www.sitepoint.com/a-step-by-step-guide-to-building-an-android-audio-player-app/), пусть ваши активити и адаптер реализуют эти интерфейсы. Но мне кажется это не лучший вариант. Если вы пишете плеер, то в дальнейшем вам понадобится играть музыку на фоне, следовательно нужен `Service`. и именно сервис будет взаимодействовать с медиаплеером. а активити и адаптер уже с сервисом. На тему плееров есть неплохой 
[**гайд**](https://www.sitepoint.com/a-step-by-step-guide-to-building-an-android-audio-player-app/)

Comment: Да ладно, класс плеера переделать в сервис вообще без проблем, суть в другом

Comment: Все я знаю про эти листнеры.